# How do i push a value from a hash onto an array of a hash?

Tags: perl, data-structures, reference, hashmap

I have a `%hashmap` and an array `@values`.

In my code the `%hashmap` is being created like this `$hashmap{$key}="$name";`

After the `%hashmap` is created i need to take it's value and add it to the same `%hashmap` but with a different key , the new hashmap looks like this :

```
@hashvalues=($name,$type,$Statement,\@parents,\@children)
$hashmap{$newkey}=\@hashvalues;
```

I want to push the `$name` from `$hashmap{$key}` into the `\@children` of the  `$hashmap{$newkey}`

This is my code so far :

```
# first i check if the $hashmap exists so i know i update it 

if(exists$hashmap{$name}){
    my $auxiliary=\@{$hashmap{$name}};
    push(@children,@$auxiliary);
}   
my @hashvalues=($name,$type,$Statement,\@parents,\@children);

$hashmap{$name}=\@hashvalues;
```

The `%hash` i want to `push` it is created here , there is no other record of it :

```
if ($parent ne @$hashvalues2[0]) {      
    $hashmap{$parent}="$child";
}
```

The value i am interested to store and push is `$child` here .

Here is the place were the same %hash will be created again but with the fields name , type etc : (not empty fields ! , they all have a value assigned earlier )

```
@hashvalues = ($name, $type, $Statement, \@parents, \@children)
$hashmap{$newkey} = \@hashvalues;
```

I want to see if the `%hash` was created before this point `@hasvalues=($name..`

So i check it with this code :

```
if (exists$hashmap{$name}) { Do Code... }
```

If there was a recording of it i want to update the %hash , by pushing the value `$child` in the `\@parents` of the `@hashvalues` , so when `%hash` with type , name .. will be made to have the $child value for the previous version of it.

Here is the order of the code :

1. `if (exists$hashmap{$name}) { Do Code; }`
2. ```
   my @hashvalues  = ($name, $type, $Statement, \@parents, \@children);
   $hashmap{$name} = \@hashvalues;
   ```
3. ```
   if ($parent ne @$hashvalues2[0]) {
       $hashmap{$parent} = "$child";
   }
   ```

Here is the whole code :

`@FileStatements` - An array of Statements
`$Statement` - a larger string where i collect all my data from

And i fill the `@hashvalues` with all the data i collect

```
my $FROMduplicate="";
 my $JOINduplicate="";
    foreach my $Statement (@FileStatements) {

        if ($Statement!~m/create/i) {
            next;
        }
        if ($Statement=~m/create user |^GRANT |^spool /gim) {
            next;       
        }
        my $name="";
        my $type="";
        my $content="";#FileStatements
        my @parents=();
        my @children=();
        my $duplicate="";
        # print $Statement."\n";

    #NAME--------------------------------------------
        my $catch = (split(/ view | trigger | table | synonym | procedure | role /i, $Statement))[1];
        $catch =~ s/^\s+//;
        $name = (split(/\s+/, $catch))[0];
        if ($name=~m/undef/gi){next;}
    #DEBUG  #print "$name\n";
    #TYPE--------------------------------------------
        if( $Statement=~m/^create or replace \w+ /i) {
        my $tmp = (split(/ replace /i, $Statement))[1];
        $tmp =~ s/^\s+//;
        $type = (split(/\s+/, $tmp))[0];
        }
        else{

        my $tmp = (split(/^create /i, $Statement))[1];  
        $tmp =~ s/^\s+//;
        $type = (split(/\s+/, $tmp))[0];
        }
        if ($type=~m/undef| undef |\s+undef\s+|\s+undef,/) {
            next;
        }

            #print "$type\n";
        #CONTENT-----------------------------------------
        #PARENTS-----------------------------------------
        my @froms = split(/ from\s+/i, $Statement); 
        my @joins = split(/ join /i, $Statement);
        foreach my $i (1..@froms-1) {
            #print Writer1 "$froms[$i]"."\n\n";
            my $from = (split(/ where |select | left |  left | right | as /i, $froms[$i])) [0];
            $from=~s/^\s+//;
            $from=~s/\(+//;
            my @Spaces = split(/, | , /,$from);
            foreach my $x (0..@Spaces-1) {
                    my $SpaceFrom = (split(/ /,$Spaces[$x])) [0];
                    $SpaceFrom=~s/;//;
                    $SpaceFrom=~s/\)+//;
                # print Writer1 $SpaceFrom."\n\n";
                    if ($SpaceFrom eq $FROMduplicate) {
                        next;
                    }
                    push(@parents,$SpaceFrom);                 
                     $FROMduplicate=$SpaceFrom;
           }  
        }
        foreach my $x (1..@joins-1){
            #print "$joins[$i]"."\n\n";
            my $join = (split(/ on /i,$joins[$x])) [0];
            $join = (split(/ /i,$joins[$x])) [0];
            #print Writer "\n\n".$join."\n\n";   
             if ($join eq $JOINduplicate) {
                next;
             }
            push(@parents,$join);
              $JOINduplicate=$join;

        }
             @parents = do { my %seen; grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @parents };
        #check hash for existence
           if(exists$hashmap{$name}){


             push(@{$hashmap[3]},@parents);
             push(@{$hashmap[0]},$name);
             push(@{$hashmap[1]},$type);
             push(@{$hashmap[2]},$Statement);
            }

        my @hashvalues=($name,$type,$Statement,\@parents,\@children);
        $hashmap{$name}=\@hashvalues;
         # push(@children,$hashmap{$name}) if( exists$hashmap{$name})   

    } 

}
```

Comment: Where does array `@hashvalues` come from? I don't see an "array of a hash" anywhere here. An example with real data would help a lot.

Comment: Too much bold, and horrible formatting make it hard for other people to read your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is far from clear, but I think I can answer this question out of context

> I want to push the $name from `$hashmap{$key}` into the `\@children` of the `$hashmap{$newkey}`

I assume you have something like this in place already

```
my %hashmap;

my ( $name, $type, $Statement, @parents, @children );

my @hashvalues = ( $name, $type, $Statement, \@parents, \@children );
$hashmap{$newkey} = \@hashvalues;
```

- Remember that the identifiers `name`, `type`, `Statement` etc. have vanished, and these five values are simply elements of an array
- The $name from `$hashmap{$key}` is the first element of the array, so it is
  `$hashmap{$key}[0]`
- The `@children` of the `$hashmap{$newkey}` is the fifth element of the array, or
  `$hashmap{$newkey}[4]`
- To push the first into the second, you need

  ```
  push @{ $hashmap{$newkey}[4] }, $hashmap{$key}[0]
  ```

*You should also use something more meaningful than `hashmap` for your identifier. The `%` says that the variable is a hash (there's no such thing as a Perl hash map) and you should use the name to describe the nature of its contents*